# Master Data Services (MDS) login name checking error

Tags: master-data-services

when I try to add a user to MDS and check the login name, the service can't resolve it. It adds a dollar sign ($) to the end of the login name, and the full name, e-mail address... cells are empty in the users details table. In case of few users it works correctly but sometimes not. Maybe there is a problem with the AD sync, but how can I fix it? Please help!

Thanks,
Dora

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  The cause was IIS Application Pool was set up under my username.  However, my password had changed.  Since the Application Pool could not authenticate the "admin", it could not check the active directory thus not being able to find the user.

I updated the application admin to a service account with a permanent password which fixed the issue for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Adding my own credentials again also works.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use full name instead of the login name and it should resolve.
EG: “John Smith” not “jsmith” .
It is working for me and you don’t have to change computer name.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but wasn't working for me. If a computer has the same name as the user login name, MDS is always using the computer name. Finally I added the computername to the list and updated the SID in the MDS database, so it is working now.